# mutate_at column names error

Tags: r, dplyr, anytime

I'm trying to apply the anytime() function from the anytime package in a dplyr chain to all columns ending with Date

I'm however getting this error.

```
Error: Unsupported Type
```

when I use

```
invoicePayment <- head(raw.InvoicePayment) %>%
  mutate_at(ends_with("Date"), funs(anytime))
```

but it's fine when I use

```
invoicePayment <- head(raw.InvoicePayment) %>%
  select(ends_with("Date")) %>%
  mutate_at(ends_with("Date"), funs(anytime))
```

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may need to wrap with `vars`

```
library(anytime)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(ends_with("Date")), anytime)
#  col1           col2_Date           col3_Date
#1    1 2017-06-07 05:30:00 2017-06-07 05:30:00
#2    2 2017-06-08 05:30:00 2017-06-06 05:30:00
#3    3 2017-06-09 05:30:00 2017-06-05 05:30:00
#4    4 2017-06-10 05:30:00 2017-06-04 05:30:00
#5    5 2017-06-11 05:30:00 2017-06-03 05:30:00
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2_Date = Sys.Date() + 0:4, col3_Date = Sys.Date() - 0:4)
```